# Android stop activity in onCreate() before calling super.OnCreate()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, resume

I am creating an app having a navigation drawer activity with fragments. At every cold start of the app, I am executing some initialization code where I load the following things:

- The user session(if the user is logged in or not)
- Registering **Retrofit** services
- Getting some data from the server to proceed with startup of the app.

This is the flow of my app when doing a cold start:

- Starting **MainActivity** and verifying the user session.
- If the session is valid, then we open the **CoreActivity**.
- If not, then we open the **LoginActivity**.

When the app is brought to the foreground after some inactivity Android tries to restart the current Activity. This means my initialization code is bypassed and `CoreActivity.onCreate()` is executed.

All my activities(except **MainActivity**) are extending the following super activity:

```
public abstract class MasterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    if (!CrmContext.getInstance().verifyContextSet(this)) {
        return;
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    onCreateAfterContext(savedInstanceState);
}
```

**In CrmContext:**

```
public boolean verifyContextSet(final Context context) {
    boolean isContextSet = applicationContext != null;
    if (isContextSet) {
        return true;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    return false;
}
```

In `verifyContextSet()` I  am doing some checks to be sure that the app has been correctly loaded. If the user session is not properly loaded.

**My problem:**

If the app is brought to the front the `CoreActivity.onCreate()` is executed and `verifyContextSet()` returns false. In this case I want to cancel the creation of **CoreActivity** and open **MainActivity** again.

When I do my `verifyContextSet()` before `super.onCreate()`, then I get this exception:

> android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {nl.realworks.crm/nl.realworks.crm.view.CoreActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2287)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)

I tried to execute `super.onCreate()` first, but then the `Fragment` inside the activity is created first. This means that my `Fragment` is recreated before my `verifyContextSet()` is executed.

So, If I try to `cancel()`/`finish()` the `onCreate()` before `super.onCreate()` has been called, then I get the `SuperNotCalledException`. If I execute `super.onCreate()` first, then the `Fragment` is initialized which is not allowed when `verifyContextSet()` returns `false`.

I want to do the following:

- Bringing the app to the foreground
- Check if the app has been initialized
- If not, then `finish()` the current activity and then restart the app to open **MainActivity**.

Comment: I have adjusted my question to make things more clear.

Comment: Did you ever get around this?

Comment: Can't remember it. It has been a while.

Comment: anybody ever resolve this?

Comment: @com2ghz Not calling `super` is a bad approach in my opinion. For me it sounds like you want to check launch mode for your activity. You might want to use`<activity android:launchMode= "singleInstance" />`

Comment: I think the issue here is not how to prevent an activity from resuming (it's been outlined) but that this whole idea is incorrectly architected and the OP is now fighting against the Android framework, to accommodate for this requirement.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini exactly!

Comment: i kind of solved my problems by not doing anything in my fragment's `onAttach()` callback, because `onAttach()` will be called from `onCreate()` of `FragmentActivity` when restoring from process death

Answer (score 1):

put your checking/validating code in an `Application` sub class

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
//in your oncreate create sessions etc.
```

now whether `MainActivity` restarts or not, you have already validated.

Note: `Application` class' `onCreate()` is the firs to run before any body.

Comment: I tried this, but it still keeps continuing starting the Activity which was opened previously. How do I prevent that the last Activity is being restarted?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to have your onCreate like this

```
super.onCreate();
if(<activity is not valid>) {
   startAnotherActivity()
   finish()
   return;
}
```

This will make sure that no other activity lifecycle method is called except onDestroy i.e. onResume, onPause, onStop, onStart.

Answer (score 0):

I think code should look like that

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Your code

}
```

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) allways as first line.

Comment: When I do this, then the super.onCreate() tries to resume/initialize the Fragment before my `verifyContextSet()` is executed

Comment: @MikeM. The previous fragment that was opened before the app went to the background. I think the code is irrelevant because I want to do my checks before my fragment get's loaded.

Comment: I have moved my check to Application.onCreate() but I can't interrupt the execution. It keeps trying to resume the previous Activity

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewModel and Observer. Basically your remaining `onCreate code` will only execute if Observer triggered.

```
onResume {

    // THIS WILL TRIGGER THE OBSERVER
    viewModel._needVerification.value = true

}

onCreate {

    super.onCreate()

    ... CREATE VIEWMODEL

    // THIS NEEDED TO HANDLE RECREATED ACTIVITY CAUSE BY SCREEN ORIENTATION ETC
    viewModel._verificationFinished.value = false

    viewModel.needVerification.observe(this, Observer{

        if (it == true) {

            verifyContextSet(final Context context) {

                if (isContextSet) {

                    if (viewModel.verificationFinished.value != true) {

                        ... DO REMAINING ONCREATE CODE 

                        viewModel._verificationFinished.value = true

                    }

                } else {

                    Start MainActivity

                }

            }

        }

  })

}
```

Comment: No, no you don't need any of this.

Comment: I change the word  "need" to "can".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of only returning from `onCreate` you need to finish the Activity first to stop other initialization callbacks to be triggered.

Just change this code

```
if (!CrmContext.getInstance().verifyContextSet(this)) {
    return;
}
```

to this

```
if (!CrmContext.getInstance().verifyContextSet(this)) {
    finish();
    return;
}
```

Comment: don't recommend finish without return after it.